# Is Spring batch suitable for multiple query datareader

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am working on a module that needs to read data from database and write to JSON file. With the following example i will try to illustrate the scenario

```
Department schema has two tables 
 1. States    columns- stateId, stateName, cityCount, debt, 
 2. City   columns- cityId, cityName, stateId, completedProjects, runningProjects
```

Need to create separate JSON file for each state.
Sample JSON-  Washington.JSON

```
{
"StateId": id,
"StateName": name,
"debt": debt,
Cities:[{
"cityId":id,
"cityName":Name,
"completedProjects":completedProjects,
"runningProjects":runningProjects
}]
}
```

For this I think We need two queries to fetch the result. One to fetch the records from states table for state details and another to fetch records from City by looping over the resultset of State table.

My Manager is suggesting to use Spring Batch for above. I have gone through some docs available online and sample applications. As per my understanding in Spring Batch Item reader we need to read all the data at once. And then we need to create a rowmapper to map the records. this rowmapper can be used by the Writer to write to files. I figured that there can not be single query to fetch the both state and city data here. I need to use the state id from first query to get cities from second query.
My Question is how do I read the data in item reader ?
Also I was wondering if Spring batch will be an ideal solution for the current situation( considering the fact there are multiple inner data like City, which need separate query).
I am sorry the post is too long..I wanted to explain the current scenerio

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a single query-base ItemReader based of a join between state+cities
2. Use a custom CompletionPolicy to break among States; in this manner you will receive a List<> of state+city bean where State is the same for every item in List<>
3. In your custom ItemWriter.write() create JSON file (this should be pretty easy)

My 2cents